# C++ - pointers in a QList

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

I have a Class called `File` which contains a `QTextEdit*` (a textbox), a `QWidget*` (used to create tabs in a `QTabWidget`), a `QString` for holding an address of a file and a `bool` to check whether the file has been saved / modified.

I store these files in a `QList` (it's just like the `std::list`).

```
void MainWindow::newFile()
{
    QWidget* tab = new QWidget( tabWidget ); //QTabWidget is a member of MainWindow, it gets automatically deleted when MainWindow gets destryoed
    tabWidget->addTab( tab, tr("New Tab") ); //Add it to the QTabWidget
    tab->setLayout( new QHBoxLayout( tab ) );

    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit( tab ); //When tab gets deleted, this also gets deleted
    tab->layout()->addWidget( textEdit );

    File *f = new File( this, textEdit, tab ); //Store both in a file
    fileList.push_back( f ); //Add it to the list (member of MainWindow)

    tabWidget->setCurrentIndex( tabWidget->count()-1 ); //Go to that tabPage
    f->textEdit()->setFocus(); //Set the focus to the textEdit
}
```

This creates a new tabpage, adds it to the `QTabWidget`, creates a layout for the tabpage, creates a new `QTextEdit`, adds it to the layout so it's filled and will automatically resize and finally it gets pushed back onto the `QList` so I can remove the tab etc.

Since the class `File` has pointers as member their objects on the heap have to be deleted. But when I try to delete them in the destructor I get a SIGSEGV and my program crashes.

```
File::~File()
{
delete m_textEdit; //QTextEdit* - Crashes here
delete m_tab; //QWidget* //Doesn't reach this line
}
```

My question now is, why does my program crash when I try to delete `m_textEdit`'s object? This only happens when I close the window.

Also, do I have to delete the File* when I remove them from the list? Or does the list do it automatically for me? If so, how do I do it?

```
//delete fileList.at(0); //This would cause a crash
fileList.removeAt( 0 ); //removing for example the first index
```

Edit: Headerfile of `File`

```
class File : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QTextEdit* m_textEdit;
    QWidget* m_tab;
    QString m_filepath;
    bool m_saved;

public:
    explicit File(QObject *parent = 0);
    File( const File& );
    File( QObject* parent, QTextEdit* textEdit = 0, QWidget* tab = 0, const QString& filepath = QString(), bool saved = true );
    ~File();

signals:
    void savedChanges( bool );

public slots:
 //Getters and setters only
};
```

Comment: You should show us the declaration of `File`. Is it obey the parent-child pattern?

Comment: @MM. You mean the header, right? I posted it. And yeah, if I'm not wrong it is parent-child pattern.

Comment: As I see your QTextEdit Object is named textEdit and not m_textEdit that you want to destroy.

Comment: What do you mean? I called the QTextEdit object textEdit in the MainWindow function and m_textEdit in the class File.

Comment: I am not so sure that even textEdit needs to be destroyed since it will get deleted when its parent gets deleted. QObject does this.

Comment: He means your code **never sets m_textEdit** to anything (and even if it did you shouldn't be deleting it anyway, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig Well it does. the constructors do and the setter functions. I didn't list all the setters but there's for each member one setter and one getter.

Comment: @Davlog Ah. ok. regardless. don't delete it. the layout owns it once it is added.

Comment: Can the title of this thread be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent of the pointers to `File` is `MainWindow` so by destroying the parent those objects will be destroyed automatically, then you don't need to `delete` them and this is wrong:

```
delete fileList.at(0);
```

On the other hand, removing an item from `fileList` doesn't hurt and it's OK:

```
fileList.removeAt(0);
```

---

This is code doesn't make sense:

```
File::~File()
{
  delete m_textEdit; //QTextEdit* - Crashes here
  delete m_tab; //QWidget* //Doesn't reach this line
}
```

Because, you're getting `m_textEdit` and `m_tab` from the constructor, and you didn't `new` them by `File`. So, it's not correct to `delete` them here. Don't touch them.

Comment: So MainWindow handles the objects of the members m_textEdit and m_tab in File?

Comment: @Davlog: Yes -- if you pass `MainWindow` as their parent to them.

Comment: I assume tabWidget is a child of MainWindow. From the code posted tab is a child of tabWidget and textEdit is a child of tab.